# Epicor 10 How can I add UserID to Quote Entry?

Tags: customization, userid, epicor10

Epicor 10.2 user 
New to this ! There is no UserID field in Quote that I could find. I want to add this to the summary page so my admins can keep track of who entered which quote, despite the territory. 
I've added a UD text box to Opportunity/Quote Entry. How do I link the current user to that field and auto-populate when a new quote is created? 
Really not sure where to start !

please help !

Answer (score 1):

I use the QuoteDtl_ChangedBy field to print the user ID on reports.